# How do I make the email field not required to signin but required for signup?

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi, swagger-ui, openapi

I have the `User` class with the `Id`, `Username`, `Password` and `Email` properties.

[image: User Class]

In Swagger UI, when trying to signin, if success, I get a JWT token in return as well with a bool: that's the case, when I got the `Email` commented out from user class,

[image: Token + true boolean]

[image: Swagger with Email outcommented from User Class]

Since both `Task<AutheticatedUser> SignIn(User user);` and
`Task<AutheticatedUser> SignUp(User user);`
takes the user as input.

Is it a way to make the `email` not being required when I sign in, to still be able to User user as input?

[image: Response 400 when email property not commented out]

It works when I comment out the `email` from the `User` class, but I want the `email` to be required when I sign up.

Comment: share your code as formatted text and be a little more specific as in what you want to achieve.

Comment: I would like to know, if there is a way to make the email property, not required when im signing in, calling the API request signin that returns 400, since both signin and signup has the class users, they both get id, username, password and email with them in the API, but as of now, i only has username and password to signin, and it returns 400 since it want email aswell

Comment: You'll probably have to define 2 separate User classes - one with the email and another one without the email. Use the former for signup, and the latter for signin.

Comment: @Niclas Probably set email value to `null` or `""` by default and later update

Comment: @NiclasEdling please do not post screenshots of text ... some people cannot view images ... also, the code cannot be copied and tested ... please remove the pictures and insert the text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use `.NET 6`/`.NET 7`.  From .NET 6 the **non-nullable property must be required**, otherwise the ModelState will be invalid.

To achieve your requirement, **the first way** is you can remove `<Nullable>enable</Nullable>` from your project file(double-click the project name or right-click the project to choose Edit Project File).

**The second way**, you can add `?` to allow nullable:

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    //other properties....
    public string? Email{ get; set; }  //change here...
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that solved it! First time trying out stackoverflow, really likeing the feedbacks and the help, thank you so much